# alert errors on trading view

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I just did the recent update on TradingView, and I'm experiencing some problems.

I have an alert set up with {{strategy.order.action}}, However this alert is triggering a 'buy' or 'sell' action/alert on my strategy.close script.

Example:

It is also triggering for a buy/sell order for the strategy.close section

I'm not exactly sure what's wrong or why this occurred. Any help would be great.

I've changed the script to strategy.entry / strategy.close but still receiving the alert for the close order.

Comment: example:Example:

if (ShortCondition)
strategy.order("Short", strategy.short)
if (ShortCondition[nBars])
strategy.close("Short", comment="Short Exit")

Answer (score 0):

In tradingview, the alert you activate on the right panel of your chart **are linked** to the version of the script.

If you change your script, you must delete the alert on tradingview on then create a new one.

Comment: Correct. I'm just confused on why trading view it creating a sell/buy alert for my strategy.close

Comment: a close is a buy or a sell no ?